# How do I perform matrix.scale on Win RT's page.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, matrix, winrt-xaml

I want to do Matrix.Scale() on the page.xaml.cs but the method does not exist.
A different type of matrix is used. I want to use the Matrix as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx . I'm quite a newbie in C#. How do I use the matrix from the link to perform my transformation and scaling. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look into your link and read that Windows RT isnt written down in the supported platforms.

There is a matrix class for xaml as well but i dont think it comes with a scale method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.matrix?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1